# How to detect player deaths in vanilla

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to know how to detect when a player dies in vanilla Minecraft, because I want to make blood using commands. Thanks for answering if you do. NOTE: I need the COMMAND for detecting a player death. I'm experienced with /scoreboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add an objective of type `stat.deaths`:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths stat.deaths
```

When a player dies, their `Deaths` score will increment.

On a clock, you can select people who have just died with `@a[score_Deaths_min=1]` (e.g: to execute a `/particle` command from them), then set their `Deaths` back to 0:

```
/execute @a[score_Deaths_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /say I just died!
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Deaths_min=1] Deaths 0
```